# Comparison of results from statsmodels ARIMA with original data

Tags: python, statsmodels

I have a time series with seasonal components. I fitted the statsmodels ARIMA with

```
model = tsa.arima_model.ARIMA(data, (8,1,0)).fit()
```

For example. Now, I understand that ARIMA differences my data. How can I compare the results from

```
prediction = model.predict()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data.plot()
prediction.plot()
```

as data will be the original data and prediction is differenced, and so has a mean around 0, different from the mean of data?

Comment: Have a look at the predict docstring and the `typ` keyword.

Comment: Thanks. It looks kinda obvious now, but when I was reading the docs it was not that simple. Maybe a bit more of indication on the docs would help?

Comment: Also, it seems that this question already surfaced on the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/pystatsmodels/QIhYf9XCyd8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/0.6.0/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.predict.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.predict) shows, if the keyword `typ` is passed to the `predict` method, the answer can be show in the original predictor variables:

```
typ : str {‘linear’, ‘levels’}

    ‘linear’ : Linear prediction in terms of the differenced endogenous variables.
    ‘levels’ : Predict the levels of the original endogenous variables.
```

So the call would be

```
model = tsa.arima_model.ARIMA(data, (12,1,0)).fit()
arima_predict = model.predict('2015-01-01','2016-01-01', typ='levels')
```