# python statsmodels: Help using ARIMA model for time series

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

ARIMA from statsmodels is giving me inaccurate answers for my output. I was wondering whether someone could help me understand what's wrong with my code.

This is a sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA

# Setting up a data frame that looks twenty days into the past,
# and has linear data, from approximately 1 through 20
counts = np.arange(1, 21) + 0.2 * (np.random.random(size=(20,)) - 0.5)
start = dt.datetime.strptime("1 Nov 01", "%d %b %y")
daterange = pd.date_range(start, periods=20)
table = {"count": counts, "date": daterange}
data = pd.DataFrame(table)
data.set_index("date", inplace=True)

print data

               count
date
2001-11-01   0.998543
2001-11-02   1.914526
2001-11-03   3.057407
2001-11-04   4.044301
2001-11-05   4.952441
2001-11-06   6.002932
2001-11-07   6.930134
2001-11-08   8.011137
2001-11-09   9.040393
2001-11-10  10.097007
2001-11-11  11.063742
2001-11-12  12.051951
2001-11-13  13.062637
2001-11-14  14.086016
2001-11-15  15.096826
2001-11-16  15.944886
2001-11-17  17.027107
2001-11-18  17.930240
2001-11-19  18.984202
2001-11-20  19.971603
```

The rest of the code sets up the ARIMA model.

```
# Setting up ARIMA model
order = (2, 1, 2)
model = ARIMA(data, order, freq='D')
model = model.fit()
print model.predict(1, 20)

2001-11-02    1.006694
2001-11-03    1.056678
2001-11-04    1.116292
2001-11-05    1.049992
2001-11-06    0.869610
2001-11-07    1.016006
2001-11-08    1.110689
2001-11-09    0.945190
2001-11-10    0.882679
2001-11-11    1.139272
2001-11-12    1.094019
2001-11-13    0.918182
2001-11-14    1.027932
2001-11-15    1.041074
2001-11-16    0.898727
2001-11-17    1.078199
2001-11-18    1.027331
2001-11-19    0.978840
2001-11-20    0.943520
2001-11-21    1.040227
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

As you could see, the data is just constant around `1` instead of increasing. What am I doing wrong here?

(On a side note, I can't pass in string dates like `"2001-11-21"` into the predict function for some reason. It would be helpful to know why.)

Comment: Try to add `typ='level'` to predict. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30108091/comparison-of-results-from-statsmodels-arima-with-original-data and the predict docstring. It's also possible to add a trend directly to the model (currently to fit).

Comment: Thanks! That fixed my problem. Admittedly, I don't understand the documentation for `ARIMA.predict` though. It must be a concept in statistics.

Comment: `typ='levels'`, not `type='level'`.  Maybe it was `'level'` in the past but documentation shows `typ : str {‘linear’, ‘levels’}`

Answer (score 10):

### TL;DR

The way you use `predict` returns a linear prediction in terms of the
**differenced endogenous variable** not a prediction of the **levels of the original endogenous variable**.

You must feed `predict` method with `typ='levels'` to change this behavior:

```
preds = fit.predict(1, 30, typ='levels')
```

See documentation of [`ARIMAResults.predict`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.predict.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.predict) for details.

### Step by step

#### Dataset

We load data you provided in your MCVE:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

raw = io.StringIO("""date        count
2001-11-01   0.998543
2001-11-02   1.914526
2001-11-03   3.057407
2001-11-04   4.044301
2001-11-05   4.952441
2001-11-06   6.002932
2001-11-07   6.930134
2001-11-08   8.011137
2001-11-09   9.040393
2001-11-10  10.097007
2001-11-11  11.063742
2001-11-12  12.051951
2001-11-13  13.062637
2001-11-14  14.086016
2001-11-15  15.096826
2001-11-16  15.944886
2001-11-17  17.027107
2001-11-18  17.930240
2001-11-19  18.984202
2001-11-20  19.971603""")

data = pd.read_fwf(raw, parse_dates=['date'], index_col='date')
```

As we may expect data are auto-correlated:

```
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot
autocorrelation_plot(data)
```

[image]

#### Model & Training

We create an [`ARIMA`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.html) [Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average) object for a given setup `(P,D,Q)` and we train it on our data using the [`fit`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.fit.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.fit) method:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA

order = (2, 1, 2)
model = ARIMA(data, order, freq='D')
fit = model.fit()
```

It returns an [`ARIMAResults`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults) object which is matter of interest. We can check out the quality of our model:

```
fit.summary()

                            ARIMA Model Results                              
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                D.count   No. Observations:                   19
Model:                 ARIMA(2, 1, 2)   Log Likelihood                  25.395
Method:                       css-mle   S.D. of innovations              0.059
Date:                Fri, 18 Jan 2019   AIC                            -38.790
Time:                        07:54:36   BIC                            -33.123
Sample:                    11-02-2001   HQIC                           -37.831
                         - 11-20-2001                                         
==============================================================================
                  coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025     0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const           1.0001      0.014     73.731      0.000       0.973      1.027
ar.L1.D.count  -0.3971      0.295     -1.346      0.200      -0.975      0.181
ar.L2.D.count  -0.6571      0.230     -2.851      0.013      -1.109     -0.205
ma.L1.D.count   0.0892      0.208      0.429      0.674      -0.318      0.496
ma.L2.D.count   1.0000      0.640      1.563      0.140      -0.254      2.254
                                    Roots                                    
==============================================================================
                   Real          Imaginary           Modulus         Frequency
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AR.1            -0.3022           -1.1961j            1.2336           -0.2894
AR.2            -0.3022           +1.1961j            1.2336            0.2894
MA.1            -0.0446           -0.9990j            1.0000           -0.2571
MA.2            -0.0446           +0.9990j            1.0000            0.2571
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And we can roughly estimate how residuals are distributed:

```
residuals = pd.DataFrame(fit.resid, columns=['residuals'])
residuals.plot(kind='kde')
```

[image]

#### Prediction

If we are satisfied with our model, then we can predict some in-sample or out-sample data.

This can be done with the [`predict`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.predict.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.predict) method which by default returns the **differenced endogenous variable** not the **endogenous variable itself**. To change this behavior, we must specify `typ='levels'`:

```
preds = fit.predict(1, 30, typ='levels')
```

Then our predictions do have the same levels of our training data:

[image]

Additionally, if we are interested to also have confidence intervals, then we can use the [`forecast`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.forecast.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.forecast) method.

#### String Argument

It is also possible to feed `predict` with strings (always use the [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format if you want to avoid troubles) or `datetime` objects:

```
preds = fit.predict("2001-11-02", "2001-12-15", typ='levels')
```

Works as expected on StatsModels 0.9.0:

```
import statsmodels as sm
sm.__version__ # '0.9.0'
```

Comment: Is there any obvious reason why the default is using "linear" and not "levels"? Why is that more natural?